# Subscriptions - Apply coupon code for the first month only, with no initial payment

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, subscriptions, coupon

I use [WooCommerce Subscription plugin](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/)

**What I would Like:**
For **new Customers only,** I would like to auto apply a coupon code for the **first payment only, on the first subscription**. I don't use a signup fee, and our payments are synchronized each 2nd day of the month.

Meaning, I would like a coupon for a users first month's payment to be X% off, one time. Then after that this coupon will not be anymore usable, for that customer.

I have tried various plugins but nothing did that trick.

Can anyone please guide me about that?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Not all payment on just first payment - mean just for first month, after that normal payment will get started. Just like starting discount will be 10% and after that 0% off.
2. Payment is sync to 2nd of the month, means all the users will be charged on the first month. So there will be no initial payment at the time of order.

Comment: **To answer your question** from [**this link**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/faq/#section-4), *"A subscription with a free trial period and no signup fee or synchronized renewals and no signup fee has no initial payment. Therefore Cart and Product coupons do not apply a discount."*